# Kyle Simpsons's OLOO adding Multiple properties after Object.create

Tags: javascript, inheritance, model, delegation

I just recently learned about Kyle Simpson's coined "OLOO" delegation model (instead of inheritance) and he went about creating objects and delegating properties and functions with a code snippet similar to below:

```
var Foo = {
    init: function(who) {
        this.me = who;
    },
    identify: function() {
        return "I am " + this.me;
    }
};

var Bar = Object.create(Foo);

Bar.speak = function() {
    alert("Hello, " + this.identify() + ".");
};

var b1 = Object.create(Bar);
b1.init("b1");
var b2 = Object.create(Bar);
b2.init("b2");

b1.speak(); // alerts: "Hello, I am b1."
b2.speak(); // alerts: "Hello, I am b2."
```

Here, Bar delegates all calls to "init" and "identify" to the "Foo" object but then after Bar is created we have to go through line-by-line and add any other properties to Bar via:

```
Bar.someAdditionalFunc = function(){ /* Do something else for Bar */ };
Bar.someAdditionalProp = { prop: 'Value' };
```

My question is this: is there any way to pre-define (or post-define) all these properties for a (potentially) big Bar without using the dot notation (Bar.PropertyName = ...) for each new property?

For example, I was thinking of doing something like this:

```
var BarTemp = {
    someAdditionalFunc: function(){ /* Do something else for Bar */ },
    someAdditionProp: { prop: 'Value' }
};

var Bar = Object.create(Foo, BarTemp);
```

And this correctly creates the Bar object with the someAdditionFunc and someAdditionalProp properties created but they are all set to 'undefined'.  I suppose this is the correct behavior but I was wondering if I am stuck with using jQuery.extend() or creating another sub-object like so:

```
var subObject = {
    someAdditionalFunc: function() {},
    someAdditionalProp: { prop: 'value' }
    // ... all other properties we want to add
}

var Bar = Object.create(Foo);
Bar.otherStuff = subObject; 
// Now I always have to reference those properties by:
//    Bar.otherStuff.someAdditionalFunc
// instead of:
//    Bar.someAdditionalFunc
```

or is there a simpler way to implement/think about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of options to do this in fewer steps, but it really depends upon your browser support requirements. The second option is also not particularly "simple", either!

#### `Object.setPrototypeOf()` (ES6)

Because this is in ES6, it's only really any use if you're using server side code where the JavaScript engine is known, otherwise you'll have to polyfill. See the [compatability chart here.](https://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es6/#Object_static_methods_Object.setPrototypeOf)

```
var foo = {
  bar: function() { console.log("bar"); }
}

var baz = {
  someProp: 'a',
  someFunc: function () { console.log("dork"); }
}


Object.setPrototypeOf( baz, foo );
baz.someFunc() // "dork"
baz.bar()      // "bar"
```

#### `Object.create( proto , propertiesObject )` (ES5)

This is more widely supported, but might still cause you issues with old versions of IE.

Bascially, you were nearly there in your question, except that you need to use [property descriptors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperties) instead of just a hash of properties and values:

```
var foo = {
  bar: function() { console.log("bar"); }
}

var b = Object.create( foo, {
  baz: {
    value: function() { console.log("baz") },
    writable: true,      // default: false
    enumerable: true,   // default: false
    configurable: true,  // default: false
  },
  defProps: {
    value: function() { console.log("default"); }
  }
});

b.bar();      // bar
b.baz();      // baz
b.defProps(); // default

for(var prop in b){
 console.log(prop); // baz, bar
}

delete b.defProps;   //typeError
b.defProps = "test"; //typeError
```

The problem with this, as illustrated with the `defProps` object above, is that the defaults for the object property descriptors are almost always not what you want, so it ends up being incredibly verbose and even more tedious.

Comment: This is way late, but thanks Ed!  I wonder if the ES6 version will even be relevant with the introduction of classes, but the ES5 version is exactly what I was looking for!